# The holomorphic map from a compact smooth curve $C$ to $\mathbb{C}P^1$ when $H^0(C,\mathcal{O}(p))=2$

Tags: complex-geometry, riemann-surfaces, complex-manifolds

Let $C$ be a compact smooth complex curve with  $H^0(C,\mathcal{O}(p))=2$.

I feel confused with the following words:

Denote by $a$ and $b$ two non-collinear sections in $H^0(C,\mathcal{O}(p))$. Then one can consider the ratio $f=a/b$ as a holomorphic map from $C$ to $\mathbb{C}P^1$.

$\bullet$ If both sections vanish at the same point $q$ then $f$ does not take the value $0$ so is constant. This contradicts the non-collinearity of $a$ and $b$.

$\bullet$  If $a$ but not $b$ vanishes at $q$ then looking at the fiber of $0\in \mathbb{C}P^1$ the degree of the map $f$ is $1$.

I don't understand "If both sections vanish at the same point $q$ then $f$ does not take the value $0$ so is constant." And does non-collinear means $a,b$ are not linear?

I also wonder how to deduce the degree is $1$ from $a(q)=0,b(q)\not=0$?

At last, how is that related to $p$?

Comment: $H^0(C,O(p))$ is the set of meromorphic functions $f$ such that for every $U, f\in O(p)(U)$ thus it is the meromorphic functions with only one pole at $p$. Since $C$ is compact this means $f$ has only one zero. If $\dim H^0(C,O(p))=2$ then $H^0(C,O(p)) = \Bbb{C} f_1+\Bbb{C}f_2$ where $Div(f_1) = q_1-p,Div(f_2) = q_2-p$. If $q_1=q_2$ then $Div(f_1/f_2) =\emptyset$ so $f_1/f_2$ is constant, contradiction. Thus $z\in C\mapsto[f_1(z):f_2(z)]$ is a surjective holomorphic map $C\to\Bbb{C}P^1$ of degree $1$, it is an isomorphism and $C\cong\Bbb{C}P^1$.

Comment: It is of degree $1$ because $Div(f_1/f_2) = q_1-q_2$ so for any $s \in \Bbb{C},  Div(f_1/f_2-s) = r-q_2$ and hence $f=f_1/f_2$ takes the value $s$ only once. This proves  the function field of $C$ is $\Bbb{C}(f)$. Also $z \mapsto [f_1:f_2]$ is locally biholomorphic, to prove it is globally biholomorphic you can look at the Cauchy integral formula for $f^{-1}$. Why don't you search for elementary texts ?

Comment: @reuns I think, an element in $H^0(C,O(p))$ is some $f$ with $(f)+(p)\ge0$, thus $f$ can be a holomorphic function, which is a constant, can not be expressed by $f_1,f_2$, right?

Comment: @reuns and can you tell me the definition of non-collinear?

Comment: With $C = \Bbb{C}P^1=\Bbb{C}\cup \infty$ and $p \in \Bbb{C}$ then $H^0(C,O(p)) = \{ (z \mapsto a+\frac{b}{z-p}), a,b \in \Bbb{C}\}= \Bbb{C} f_1+\Bbb{C}f_2= \Bbb{C}\ \  (f_1+f_2)+\Bbb{C}f_2$ where $f_1(z)=1, f_2(z)= \frac1{z-p}$ and $Div(f_2) = \infty-p$. For any $q\in C - \{p\}$ then $Div( f_2-f_2(q)) = q-p$ which is what you need to say for any $g$ meromorphic with $Div(g) = \sum_j n_j q_j$  and the $q_j \ne p$ then $g =c\prod_j (f_2-f_2(q_j))^{n_j}$

Comment: @reuns and why do you need compactness to show $f\in H^0(C,O(p))$ has only one zero? A meromorphic function on any Riemann surface has degree $0$, which is enough right? Actually, I don't know how to get $f$ has one zero by compactness, can you explain?

Comment: $\Bbb{C}$ is a non-compact Riemann surface. How many zeros and poles does $\frac{z^2}{z-1}$ and $\frac{\sin z}{z-1}$ have. For $C$ compact $f$ has the same number of zeros and poles by the argument principle : let $\gamma$ a closed curve enclosing all of them, then $\frac{df}{f}$ is a meromorphic one-form, you can modify the curve to $\gamma=\bigcup_{l=1}^m \gamma_l\bigcup_{l=1}^m\gamma_{\sigma(l)}^-$ for some permutation $\sigma$, thus $\int_\gamma \frac{df}{f}=\sum_{l=1}^m \int_{\gamma_l}\frac{df}{f}-\sum_{l=1}^m \int_{\gamma_{\sigma(l)}}\frac{df}{f}=0$

Comment: Of course you are supposed to look first at the examples given by $\Bbb{C}P^1$ and $\Bbb{C}/(\Bbb{Z+iZ})$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass%27s_elliptic_functions